# Pseudocode array notation confusion

Tags: java, arrays, pseudocode, notation

I'm looking at some pseudocode for an algorithm. One line of the pseudocode is this:

`hs <- { (a, b) | a <- m, b <- l }`

Where `m` and `l` are both arrays of objects.

What does this mean exactly? My interpretation is that it pairs each `m` with each `l` and stores them in array `hs`, like so:

Suppose `m = {m1,m2}` and `l = {l1,l2,l3,l4}`.

Then  `hs = {(m1,l1),(m1,l2),(m1,l3),(m1,l4),(m2,l1),(m2,l2),(m2,l3),(m2,l4)}`

Is this the right way of thinking about it?

---

As context was requested, this is pseudocode for the design of a hyper heuristic, using reinforcement learning based roulette wheel selection. `m` and `l` contain an array of mutation heuristics and local search heuristics, respectively. `hs` is intended as an array that pairs each of these heuristics together, so that they can be applied to the problem domain sequentially. As in, apply `mutational heuristic m_i` and then `local search heuristic l_j`. It's just not clear if they should be paired in the way I have described, or in some other way.

Comment: Who knows? It could mean anything as there's no standardized pseudocode. Where does it come from?

Comment: "hs is intended as an array that pairs each of these heuristics together," is a list defined by comprehsion, check the example in haskell, this language use a notation very similar to notation math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That you think is correct, this is a list by comprehesion definition, and `(a, b)` is a set with the `a` and `b` value.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension

Example in haskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension

Comment: Yes, my first instinct was that it's a Haskell-like list comprehension when I saw this, hence my suggested interpretation. I think you are probably right!

Comment: Yes, but this is not like a for inside a for, if the m or l have a different size a possible result is {(a1,b1), (a2,b2), (a3,b3), (a4)}

Comment: Indeed, but as this is for an iterated local search heuristic, in which you have a mutation heuristic applied to a problem domain, followed by applying a local search heuristic, this process would break down if we had `a4` on its own as you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

If that line of pseudocode is to be interpreted like the mathematical notation for a set, then yes, that is the only plausible option IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think your interpretation its pretty right, but this can be reasonable too:

If we get your example vars:

`hs = ({m1, m2}, {l1, l2, l3, l4})`

it can be think as a some kind of coordinate for a discrete space.

If you provide a context (or complete pseudocode) we could make a more precise interpretation

Comment: But this `hs = ({m1, m2}, {l1, l2, l3, l4})` is a set of two groups.

Comment: If we think mathematically, you're right  `{` `}`denotes a set. But in this case due to the nature of a set we can not group in this form: `hs = {(m1,l1),(m1,l2),(m1,l3),(m1,l4),(m2,l1),(m2,l2),(m2,l3),(m2,l4)}` because a set is an unordered collection and you can' determine an specific combination. It has more sense to me if we think `{` `}`as an array notation like you do in your question.

Comment: Context has been given, thank you for the suggestion